# bind dynamically created elements to javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the code below to set up forms with a particular class, can anyone tell me how can I bind new instances of those forms that may be created dynamically, so that their submit event will fire?

The forms are created by doing a get on newly created database items and returning a partial with the new data, then resetting just that part of the view, but the new forms are not bound to the submit event.

```
import $ from "jquery";

function setupDocumentDeleteForms() {

    var deleteDocumentForms = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('deleteDocumentForm'));
    if (deleteDocumentForms === undefined || deleteDocumentForms === null || !deleteDocumentForms.length) {
        return;
    }

    deleteDocumentForms.forEach(form => {
        form.onsubmit = (e) => {
            //do stuff
        }
    });

}


export default setupDocumentDeleteForms;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation on the nearest static ancestor.

```
document // or nearest static ancestor
 .addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    if(e.target.matches('.deleteDocumentForm')){
        // handle submit event on e.target
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. This would sit as a script on the partial where the new element is created?

Comment: @DarkW1nter What do you mean?